# Error when calling webservice: "The type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced"

Tags: asp.net

I can call my web service by accessing it in a web browser on the server but when I call it via a Soap client from my test client, I get the following exception:

"The type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."

..rest of the stack trace is below.

```
   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)

   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)

   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)

   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)

   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerType..ctor(Type type, WebServiceProtocols protocolsSupported)

   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()

   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Now I have this System.dll added as a reference in my web service project and it is set to copy to local. That dll isn't in the GAC on the server (but is locally on my development server) - is that going to be the issue?

I have the following section in my web.config:

```
<add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
<add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
<add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
```

I don't get it? If the dll is in the bin folder and that reference is there as well as being added to my project, what is it complaining about?

These are the dlls in my bin folder:

```
Devart.Data.dll
Devart.Data.Linq.dll
Devart.Data.Oracle.dll
Devart.Data.Oracle.Linq.dll
Oracle.DataAccess.dll
System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
System.Configuration.dll
System.Data.dll
System.Data.Entity.dll
System.dll
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
System.Web.dll
System.Web.Services.dll
System.Xml.dll
```

I'm genuinely stumped, does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Comment: in your project, look at your references, take a look at the path of the system.dll reference, is the path indicating that you are referencing the GAC version or the bin version? if the path points to the GAC version you will need to remove the reference and readd the reference to the bin version.

Comment: Dylan, I believe it is referencing the gac version but selecting copy to local puts it into the bin folder, are you saying keep it there as part of my project and then point the reference directly at it? That would certainly help because I may not be able to add it to the gac on the server. I will not know if this works until Monday but please put that as a potential answer so I can accept it after then! Thanks!

Comment: Yep, keep it there and reference it instead of the GAC version and it will travel with your project when you deploy and it will work on the server

Answer (score 0):

in your project, look at your references, take a look at the path of the system.dll reference, is the path indicating that you are referencing the GAC version or the bin version? if the path points to the GAC version you will need to remove the reference and re-add the reference to the bin version.

Comment: It is but when I add the reference and browse to the dll in the bin folder, it still has the reference pointing at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll"